# Does Process Cube eliminate the need for SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas

I am trying to understand how SQL Server Analysis Services fits into the Business Intelligence field.

I have used SSIS to create copy databases and then SSRS to produce reports, which are accessed by he users.

I know that SSAS is a database engine, which allows you to create Cubes.  There is an option in SSAS to process cube (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216366(v=sql.80).aspx). Is SSAS a replacement for SSIS as it seems to do the ETL for you (using process cube)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609062/why-do-we-need-ssis-and-star-schema-of-data-warehouse and COTW's answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030712/what-is-the-best-approach-to-get-from-relational-oltp-database-to-olap-cube

Answer (score 2):

SSIS is an ETL tool providing you with the ability to move, manipulate and consolidate (from multiple sources) data.  SSIS tends to be a developer tool used to get the data in the correct shape either for an application or a reporting tool.

SSAS is a cube building tool providing the business with the ability to slice and dice the data ad-hocly.  Developers will build cubes, however the consumers will tend to by the business.

I have seen instances of SSAS cubes built pulling data directly from source, but these tend not to work very well, due to the load on the source systems and the complexity involved in structuring the data correctly.

A more typical approach is to utilise SSIS to pull (possibly only daily differences) and stage the data into a dimensional model that can then be cleanly consumed by SSAS.  This way both tools are playing to their strengths - SSIS moves the data around and SSAS presents the data in an efficient and user friendly way.